# getche() with while loop

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I want to make a simple program that counts the number of words and characters in it .

I found the following code sample:

```
char ch = 'a';
int Wcont = 1; // to count the number of words in the phrase
int Chcont = 0;
while (ch != '\r'){
ch = getche();
if ( ch == ' ' ) 
   Wcont++
// to the end of program 
}
```

> input : Welcome
>
> output : Wcont = 1 , Chcont = 8

If change the condition on it:

```
if ( ch == ' ' || ch == '\r')
```

then number of words increases by 1
and number of Characters decrease by 1

> input : Welocme
>
> output : Wcont = 2 , Chcont = 7

I don't understand how does `getche()` works and how it interacts with the screen. I also wonder why in the condition there is `ch == '\r'` and why the loop must stop when `ch == '\r'` is false.

Comment: This has nothing to do with [getche](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) (it's for _Linux_, although based your code snippet I tend to think you run it on _MAC_; anyway it doesn't matter). It's the expected behavior. BTW, the snippet is missing the `Chcont` variable incrementing part (although it's not very hard to guess where it is :) ).

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop tests the last `char` read and then reads the next one. You should use the following:

```
while ((ch = getche()) !='\r')
```

or alternatively:

```
    while(true)
    {
     ch = getche();
     if(ch=='\r')
      break;
.....
    }
```